# Delay in audio submission via UDP packets

Tags: android, audio, udp

I'm currently developing an application to transmit audio. I have two services running, one to receive it, one to send it. The important stuff of the sender looks like this:

```
            final DatagramSocket dSocket = new DatagramSocket();

            android.os.Process
                    .setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            Log.d(TAG, "Thread starting...");
            int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            AudioRecord arec = new AudioRecord(
                    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, 11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];
            Log.d(TAG, "Starting to record, buffersize=" + buffersize);
            arec.startRecording();

            while (isRunning && !isInterrupted()) {

                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Recording..");
                    arec.read(buffer, 0, buffersize);
                    DatagramPacket dPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer,
                            buffersize);

                    for (Peer cur : mPeers) {
                        if(cur.isSelf) continue;

                        dPacket.setAddress(InetAddress
                                .getByName(cur.IP_ADDRESS));
                        dPacket.setPort(Config.UDP_PORT);
                        dSocket.send(dPacket);
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

This code works and submits audio packets.

The receiver service looks like this:

```
            // DatagramSocket dSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            DatagramChannel dChannel = DatagramChannel.open();
            DatagramSocket dSocket = dChannel.socket();

            dSocket.setReuseAddress(true);
            dSocket.setSoTimeout(2000);
            dSocket.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Config.UDP_PORT));

            Log.d(TAG, "DatagramSocket open.");

            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_URGENT_AUDIO);

            int buffersize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

            AudioTrack aTrack = new AudioTrack(
                    AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, 11025,
                    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, buffersize,
                    AudioTrack.MODE_STREAM);

            DatagramPacket dPacket = new DatagramPacket(
                    new byte[buffersize], buffersize);
            Log.d(TAG, "Packet with buffersize=" + buffersize);
            aTrack.play();
            Log.d(TAG, "Playing track..");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[buffersize];

            while (isRunning && !isInterrupted()) {
                try {
                    dSocket.receive(dPacket);
                    buffer = dPacket.getData();

                    aTrack.setPlaybackRate(11025);
                    aTrack.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            aTrack.stop();
```

This also works, but after sending for more than a couple of seconds, there is a huge delay, the packets do still arive but slow and the audio playback simply "lags" - what can I do to improve the quality? This is a direct peer-to-peer connection, no servers involved. Should I increase the buffer size? The current buffer size is the minimum buffer size I get from Android, which is 1024 on my devices (two Galaxy Nexus). BTW, the services to start another thread, which has its priority set to "URGENT" (which I believe is the highest available). For my purposes, the mPeers list only has one peer, so the "for" loop is not really delaying this I'd guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the delay is gone. What I've done is that I've simply increased the UDP packet's buffer size. The minimum buffer size I received from Android was (on my devices) 1024 bytes. Now I do something like this:

```
int maxBufferSize = 4096; // my value. see what's working best for you.
int minBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(11025,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
                AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
int actualBufferSize = Math.max(minBufferSize, maxBufferSize);
```

With 4 KB buffer, the audio transmission is really good and there is absolutely no delay.

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked what happens when you remove the network-related part of the sender-loop? I.e., does the read()-call from the microphone return immediately? Also, you describe that packets arrive slowly, but have you checked if there is a large delay between when they are sent as well?

The reason I am asking is that the phenomena you describe could be caused by the send socket blocking, because it's buffer is full. If the socket is blocking, the send()-call will take a long time to complete. Unless you have very high-bandwidth traffic, or a very slow CPU, it should not happen with UDP sockets (they are typically fire and forget), but is worth checking.

In order to avoid blocking, create a non-blocking socket. I am not too familiar with Java networking, but it seems like a [DatagramChannel](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/DatagramChannel.html) is needed to do this.